# How can I make a specific set of iptables rules permanent?

Tags: server, startup, reboot, firewall, iptables

Is there a "best practice" or standard to make a few iptables rules permanent? I mean: automatically applied upon a system reboot?

I am using a VPS with Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).

Thank you.

BIG EDIT: I don't want ANY rule to be persisted (like `iptables-persistent` package does). I want only my own specific set to be reloaded... if other rules are eventually added by running iptables, these should be discarded...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The simplest method is to use
[iptables-save](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/iptables-save) and
[iptables-restore](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/iptables-restore) to
save the currently-defined iptables rules to a file and (re)load them
(e.g., upon reboot).

So, for instance, you would run

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.conf
```

to save your current iptables rules to `/etc/iptables.conf` and then insert these lines in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
# Load iptables rules from this file
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```

Comment: +1 Your answer is perfect to my original question. It also made me realize what I really want, so I had to change the question from "How can I make iptables rules permanent?" to "How can I make a specific set of iptables rules permanent?"

Comment: If you can, please, do a little edit to your answer to reflect the change in the question... I'll be happy to accept it! I need to use `iptables-save` once, and reload always (iptables-restore at /etc/rc.local sounds good).

Comment: If you're getting `permission denied` when you try to use `>` then [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/550808/574190) will be useful.

Comment: Use `sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf"` instead of `sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf`

Comment: rc.local is deprecated use [systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471824/what-is-the-correct-substitute-for-rc-local-in-systemd-instead-of-re-creating-rc)

Answer (score 36):

A Quick Update to this as you might be using 12.04 now and things are better.

The `iptables-persistent` package now solves this issue. To install,

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

The rules defined when the package is installed are saved and used on each subsequent boots. New rules loaded are discarded at reboot.

The config file if you do need to change them (once `iptables-persistent` is installed) is  `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` or  `/etc/iptables/rules.v6` for ipv4 and ipv6 iptables respectively.

Comment: If you make an edit to `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`, how do you get it applied [officially]? Currently I'm doing `sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Comment: @BrunoBronosky Maybe you should make the change to iptables, then do `sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` to persist it.

Answer (score 25):

Better than `/etc/rc.local` is to add a line in `/etc/network/interfaces` after saving the iptable's rules, like this

```
post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

or it's the same to put the file inside `/etc/network/if-down.d/` or `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` or `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/` or `/etc/network/if-up.d/`.

Comment: @Kreker: please do clarify, how your approach is better than executing a restoring script from `rc.local` ? does the other approach not work in some cases ?

Comment: Adding it to the network configuration causes it to be re-loaded after you run the "service networking restart" command. It's not limited to system starts.

Comment: Why would one post-up iptables-restore when an interface is going down?