# Open a port on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, iptables

I have seen similar threads, but they didn't help me.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab108.5 x86_64) on my VPS.

I ran a node.js application on port 9000, but this port is closed, so I can't see my web page using a web browser via the Internet.

My opened ports:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      752/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      366/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      454/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      611/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      485/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      599/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      454/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      611/master
```

I was trying to execute the following commands:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

But it didn't help me. 
Moreover, the /etc/iptables.rules file is missing, so I couldn't save changes using the following command:
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules

Could you help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't see `port 9000` with command `netstat` in `listening` you app not running or maybe is better to say, your server do not expect connection on that port.

Comment: And what should I do if my server don't expect connection on that port?

Comment: Start app. Do you have any log from app start?

Comment: @2707974, yes, you're right. I tried use another VPS and everything was working well even without opening of additional ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't see `port 9000` with command `netstat` in `listening` you app not running or maybe is better to say, your server do not expect connection on that port.

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

To make the change permanent

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf # Save this changes to file
touch /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables # Create file to call conf from
echo "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf" >> /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables # Add this line to this file
chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables  # Make the script executable
```

Original [Source](https://codewithintent.com/how-to-setup-access-to-mongodb-in-production-with-local-clients-robomongo-humongous-io/)

Comment: The `To make the change permanent` didn't work for me, but [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/315461/73128) one did.