# Running an iptables script at boot and when connections change

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I am using a script (one that I have created with fwbuilder) to set up my  `iptables` firewall. Since the device we are talking about is a notbook rather than a server in a quasi static network, I need to run the script whenever the interfaces change, e.g. because I switch wifi on and of.

How do I achieve that reliably way, such that my notebook does not stay unprotected, e.g. at boot time or during initialization of any of the interfaces.

**Edit**

How about placing a symlink to the script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/` (https://people.freedesktop.org/~lkundrak/nm-docs/NetworkManager.html). Does that make sense?

Comment: Your interface name is always the same aka wlan0. You need script based on ip address range? You need fw rules for service on notebook? You need rules based on connected SSID? What you wish to do?

Comment: No, if I e.g. deactivate wifi on my notebook the corresponding interface (wlp3s0) disappears according to `ifconfig`. Note that I could e.g. also connect/deconect external network adapters. What I need is a mechanism that runs the script at boot and whenever the interfaces or their connection status changes such that the rules are always apt, as defined in the script, no matter where I am.

Comment: You could adapt my `net-o-matic` script, `git clone https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/66890/423684