# How I can block specific IP's using iptables?

Tags: command-line, iptables

How I can block specific IP's? And as I know, if I somehow block them, it will be not blocked again after reboot. How I can make a script which will block specific IP's?

Comment: How I can use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this rule. In `--src` you also can define various IPs seperated by `,` (and without spaces!)

```
iptables -A INPUT --src <the specific IP> -j DROP
```

Be careful not to lock yourself out though!

For keeping them after reboot read [how-can-i-make-a-specific-set-of-iptables-rules-permanent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66890/how-can-i-make-a-specific-set-of-iptables-rules-permanent)

---

A quite complete and easy to maintain iptables setup I've found is

[DigitalOcean: How to implement a basic firewall template with iptables on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-basic-firewall-template-with-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: It would be nice, if you can explain more, so I need to do this in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4/v6` file?

Comment: No you run it as command in the terminal.