# Port forwarding ports to one hosts

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to forward a port to another port in a Linux system (Ubuntu) (I don't want to do this between two Linuxes and I want it to be done only in one Linux itself)
Is there a way to forward a port to another port on Linux?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1043754/1004020

Comment: Please add details to the question a) which release of Ubuntu you are running, b) which service / protocol is expected on the port to be forwarded, c) which port you want to forward to which.